# i am unable to compare the text widget data with a string in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def on_entry_click_text(event):
    if(speech_text.get('1.0', END) == 'Click and Say...'):#<-not working
        speech_text.delete('1.0',END) # delete all the text in the entry
        speech_text.insert(END,'') #Insert blank for user input
        speech_text.config(fg = 'black')

winchat=Tk()
speech_text=Text(winchat)
speech_text.bind("<FocusOut>",on_focusout_text)
speech_text.insert(END,'Click and Say...')
speech_text.pack()
```

i have set the value of the text field 'Click and Say...' and want when ever the user clicks the text box data clears out.

Comment: There are no obvious mistakes in your code. We can't help you without a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey my code is working and its also calling the function when clicked on it but it is not accepting the if condition and neither showing any error

Comment: Before asking such a basic question, you need to do some basic debugging. Did you think to print out the result of `speech_text.get('1.0', END)` to see if it contains what you assume it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first debug the code to find where the problem lies.

At the `if` statement, include an `else` so that you can see if the if returns as `False`.

Then you know it is not throwing an error.

If might be throwing an error, yet TKinter is ignoring it at a different level i.e. ignoring the whole function as one error.  This function does not work, dont care why, move on..

So..

You put a `try` / `except` clause in the function.

You just use `Exception` to catch all errors and you can anaylse to see if you are passing in the wrong type for the function to work..

here is an example based on your code above..

```
def on_entry_click_text(event):

    try:
        if(speech_text.get('1.0', END) == 'Click and Say...'):#<-not working
            speech_text.delete('1.0',END) # delete all the text in the entry
            speech_text.insert(END,'') #Insert blank for user input
            speech_text.config(fg = 'black')

        else:
            print('It seems to work if it got to here with no errors')

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error is: ', e)
```

Once you have this information, you can either fix it yourself or put another question here, including what the errors or problem is in better detail..

Comment: it is going on else statement i have also switched from text to enter widget and it is working ...thinking why it is not working on it

Comment: speech_text.get("1.0","end-1c")

Comment: just converted my

Comment: speech_text.get('1.0', END) to speech_text.get("1.0","end-1c")

Comment: No problem;. please select the green tick as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When your second index to `get` is `END` (equivalent to the index `”end”`), the result is guaranteed to have the trailing newline that is automatically added by the widget.

You should use `”end-1c”` (“end minus one character”) to get exactly what the user entered.